# Clean up NotifyIcons of non-existent processes in system tray

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-7

There are lots of NotifyIcon that belonged to processes that were terminated.
(So far I've seen up to 24 such icons.)
If user moves the mouse cursor over these icons, they disappear.

How do I programmatically clean up all "dead" NotifyIcons?

**EDIT 1:**

Some deep googling shows that it is possible to enumerate HWNDs of NotifyIcons.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c4f60ce-3573-433d-994e-9c17f95187f0/finding-which-applications-and-services-are-listed-in-the-system-tray?forum=csharpgeneral

Further work is trivial. Will try it later.

Comment: Write a mail client that sends an e-mail to the CEO of the application vendor, whenever one of their applications crashes, leaving an icon in the taskbar notification area behind. This may not remove the icons immediately, though.

Comment: Notification icons are not windowed. Whatever your link says, it doesn't tell you how to get window handles of notification icons, because they don't have window handles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's working solution for Windows 7.
For other versions the window classes and names might be different.
Use spyxx.exe tool do inspect tree of windows.

```
   HWND Get_Notification_Area_1()
    {            
        HWND hWnd = ::FindWindowA("Shell_TrayWnd", NULL);
        if (hWnd)
            hWnd = ::FindWindowExA(hWnd, NULL, "TrayNotifyWnd", NULL);
        if (hWnd)
            hWnd = ::FindWindowExA(hWnd, NULL, "SysPager", NULL);
        if (hWnd)
            hWnd = ::FindWindowExA(hWnd, NULL, "ToolbarWindow32", "User Promoted Notification Area");
        return hWnd;
    }

    HWND Get_Notification_Area_2()
    {            
        HWND hWnd = ::FindWindowA("NotifyIconOverflowWindow", NULL);
        if (hWnd)
            hWnd = ::FindWindowExA(hWnd, NULL, "ToolbarWindow32", "Overflow Notification Area");
        return hWnd;
    }

    void Process_Notification_Area(HWND hWnd)
    {
        if(!hWnd)
            return;
        RECT rcClient;
        BOOL bRet = ::GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
        if(!bRet)
            return;
        for(int y = rcClient.bottom - 16; y >= 0; y -= 16)
            for(int x = rcClient.right - 16; x >= 0; x -= 16)
                ::PostMessageA(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, NULL, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
    }

    void Clean_Up_Notification_Area()
    {
        Process_Notification_Area( Get_Notification_Area_1() );
        Process_Notification_Area( Get_Notification_Area_2() );
    }
```

Comment: Confirmed working under Windows 10 20H2 without changes

Answer (score 0):

> How do I programmatically clean up all "dead" NotifyIcons?

You cannot. There is not API for this. I suppose that you could script moving the mouse cursor over this part of the screen, but that's just about the best you can do.

Comment: Well, I suppose you have some experience in this topic. Could you explain your answer in more detail? Can I enumerate HWNDs of NotifyIcons and send them WM_MOUSEHOVER? Can I get ProcessHandle from HWND, check its existence and close NotifyIcon if process does not exist? Explain, why not.

Comment: There's not really any more detail. I said that this can't be done by fair means. You can't get an HWND for the notify icons, they aren't windows. You can't send them messages since their owner windows are dead. All you can do is fake mouse input. User will see the cursor move.

Comment: Let's see, these NotifyIcon are contained in Notification Area which is window (checked with Process Hacker) belonging to explorer.exe. Restarting explorer.exe cleans the Notification Area. Well, can I send some WM_MOUSEHOVERs to HWND of Notification Area?

Comment: You can do that. Does the shell respond to those messages in the way you desire? Anyway, I'm not sure I can offer you any more. You seem to have moved on from the original question. I'm sorry I was of no help.